# Compare two std::strings to see if they match c++

Tags: c++, mfc

I am trying to compare two std::strings to see if the string is in the second string. However when I do this with "8eN" I doesn't work and doesn't return the correct COLOR - on the contrary when I use "8e" it works, so I am not sure what is going on here, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Using Microsoft Visual c++ 6.0 (Legacy app :( )

## Here is my code

```
int CTcborder2::ColorOfFill()
{
    CString csGrade = m_border->csPuc; // this will be "8eN"

    std::string s((LPCTSTR)csGrade); //convert to std::string
    std::string t = "8eN"; // see if this string is in std::string s
    
    if(strstr(s.c_str(), t.c_str())) //only works with "8e" when I use "8eN" it doesn't return the correctly. 
        return COLOR;
    
}
```

Comment: C++ 6.0? What does that even mean?

Comment: Microsoft Visual C++ 6.0, for the youngsters out there.

Comment: Builder C++ 6.0?

Comment: Correct @Sneftel

Comment: [`std::string::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find)

Comment: Hum. I thought that `CString` had a find method; saves all that conversion stuff. What do the docs say?

Comment: If the question is about `std::string`, you could probably simplify your example even further by replacing `CString csGrade = m_border->csPuc;` with something self-contained -- and therefore more easily reproducible.

Comment: I'd stick with `CString` on Visual Studio 6.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use C-functions in C++ when you don't have to, just use the `std::string::find` or `std::search` by

```
int CTcborder2::ColorOfFill()
{
    CString csGrade = m_border->csPuc; // this will be "8eN"

    std::string s((LPCTSTR)csGrade); //convert to std::string
    std::string t = "8eN"; // see if this string is in std::string s

    if(s.find(t) != std::string::npos)
        return COLOR;

}
```

Comment: LOL thats what you get when you try to help a question with questionable quality

Comment: @Default Better now?